# Is it possible to share an ODBC connection with other computers on the network?

Tags: windows, ssh, odbc

I will try my best here but I am going a little out of my comfort zone so bear with me.

Computer A: Windows XP Pro
Computer B: Windows 7

Computer A has an SSH Tunnel to our web server (linux). Computer A uses an ODBC connection to connect to the tunnel as part of a requirement for a client app to run.

So far that is working perfectly.

Computer B is on the same network and wants to run the same client app as Computer A.

Is is possible for Computer B to use the ODBC connection from Computer A to connect that client app?

If not, how do I share the tunneled connection across the network so I don't have to create multiple connections on each client?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your ssh connection/tunnel is being created with PuTTY, you can select the "Local ports accept connections from other hosts" option when you set up the tunnel.

This is the same as using *ssh -g* (eg on Linux or Cygwin).

That way, you should be able to connect to whichever local port you've chosen for the tunnel from other machines on your LAN.